# I am able to query my api call, but i am not able to show it via angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui

I have made an JSON api. I like to query this with angular.js. On my webserver i see the request comes in, and returns a status 200, so the data are called by angular. For some reason however, i am not able to display on my screen.

```
The url for the JSON is:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/food/myjson/
```

The output i then receive on my screen when i directly call the url with chrome is:

```
[{"persons": 4, "name": "Pasta Bolognese", "description": "Pasta met een saus op tomaten basis"}, {"persons": 2, "name": "Pasta Carbonara", "description": ""}, {"persons": 4, "name": "Pizzadeeg voor Big Green Egg", "description": ""}, {"persons": 2, "name": "Low and Slow Ribs", "description": ""}]
```

My html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="UserCtrl">
        dish = {{ dish }}<br/>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

my script:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('UserCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {


  $scope = {};

  $scope.dish = '';

  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/food/myjson/'
  })
  .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.dish = data;
  })
  .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    // something went wrong :(
  });
}]);
```

I have tried also to iterate on the data, because an array comes back. I have done this like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="UserCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="x in dish">
            {{ x.name }}<br/>
        </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

But also no response. But the json call is done whenever i refresh the screen.

I think i am missing something basic here, but i cannot seem to figure it out. Any help would be great!

Maybe there is a way to just plainly put everything in the scope on the screen, for like debugging purposes?

Comment: did you try to console.log(data) in the success callback function to check that you get the expected data?

Comment: well i tried that now. but i think data is empty although a call is done to the api. i check it by putting $scope.dish = '', to scope.dish = [{{"name": "Pasta Carbonara"}}]. When i did this, the expected output was displayed. So for some reason the api call is done, but the output is not put in the scope...

Comment: Don t init your $scope you don t have to do this $scope is injected and instatiate via $injector it s already init

Comment: try changing the $http url to `url: '/food/myjson'`

Comment: If console.log(data) shows that data is empty, then looks like there is a problem getting the data from the server. Can you post the code where you serve the data from the server?

Answer (score 0):

This is the line that is tripping you up...

```
$scope = {};
```

By doing this you are overwriting the object that is being injected into your controller, you can feel free to add on to it, but don't completely set it to something new.

After you remove that you'll want to go w/ your ng-repeat example you included as the returned data is an array, although when looking at that you have a div tag that is not being closed, so you'll want to add another `<\div>`

Comment: Well thanks for your input. However it didnt solve it.

Comment: Set $scope to something in your error handler and change your binding to {{dish|json}} this week output your object as json.